# how to send contacts over xmpp using smack in a chat?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, vcf-vcard

I am developing a chat application in android. In that i want to send contact from sender to receiver similar to whatsapp/telegram.I know there is Vcard XEP in xmpp. But i do not know how to use it. Please can any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send the information as document only. What you can do is send a special key in the document, and if you find that key fire an intent to add the contact using the data from the document. let me know if you need help with code.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yes can you give sample code for it?.

Answer (score 0):

for get conttact firest need to `save` entry in vacrd, to getcontact `loadVCard`.

```
public class SmackVCardHelper {
        public static final String FIELD_STATUS = "status";

        private Context context;
        private XMPPConnection con;

        public SmackVCardHelper(Context context, XMPPConnection con) {
            this.context = context;
            this.con = con;
        }

        public void save(String nickname, byte[] avatar) throws SmackInvocationException {
            VCard vCard = new VCard();
            try {
                vCard.setNickName(nickname);
                if (avatar != null) {
                    vCard.setAvatar(avatar);
                }
                vCard.setField(FIELD_STATUS, context.getString(R.string.default_status));
                vCard.save(con);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
            }
        }

        public void saveStatus(String status) throws SmackInvocationException {
            VCard vCard = loadVCard();
            vCard.setField(FIELD_STATUS, status);

            try {
                vCard.save(con);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
            }
        }

        public String loadStatus() throws SmackInvocationException {
            return loadVCard().getField(FIELD_STATUS);
        }

        public VCard loadVCard(String jid) throws SmackInvocationException {
            VCard vCard = new VCard();
            try {
                vCard.load(con, jid);

                return vCard;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
            }
        }

        public VCard loadVCard() throws SmackInvocationException {
            VCard vCard = new VCard();
            try {
                vCard.load(con);
                return vCard;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please do not add code only as answer. Explain it, so that OP and others can learn from it